# fstream Reading numeric output from a file and outputting the sum to another file

Tags: c++, fstream

I am currently trying to read from a file that is in the format of

Gerry       $300

Thom        $500

Gus         $700

and attempting to output the total amount of money to another file.

How would I go about this?  All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know how to successfully open inFile, read it, open the outFile and output to it, I'm just not sure how to add the total amounts together to be displayed.

Comment: Posting your code would get you a much better response.  We're not here to do your homework but will lend you a hand where you are running into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you know how to input and output to the files already, you just need to do the calculation between the input and output. So, input the values to variables, then add the variables and store the result in another variable. Output the result variable to the new file.

For example:

```
inData >> a >> b >> c;
result = a + b + c;
outData << result << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

define input file stream and open your file

```
ifstream file("file directory");
```

now we'll read it line by line so we need a string to save each line

```
string line;
```

getline function will return false when it reaches the end of the file

```
while(getline(file,line)){
           // you can use a string stream to easily divide the string according to spaces
          istringstream ss(line); //now it contains your line
          string word;

          //now every time you do ss>>word you will get a the next word after space so you can make a loop and stop at the index of word u like to 
while(ss>>word){
//some code to stop when you find your word    }
```

}
now just make a variable and keep adding the numbers to it and finally print it to output file stream